# how to insert or update into database in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I would like to insert to update the value into the database if it does not exist if it exists then date otherwise insert how can I do try this way doesn't get success

```
fetchRecordFromFile.forEach(el => {
    if(getDataFromDB.indexOf(el.city) > -1)
        {
            Post.create(el ,function(err,data_news){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Inserted which are not before into database")
                }
            })
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you also post the error that you are getting in the console when you are trying to insert document in mongo?

Comment: I am not getting any error it is not stopping to insert duplicate

Comment: It should says if el.city exists then it should not insert even it should update or does not exist it should insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting in a database is an asynchronous operation. Hence if you are executing them in a loop, make sure you use for-in loops.

I would suggest modifying the function in the following way:

```
async Function insertRecords() {
  for(const record of fetchRecordFromFile) {
     const cityRecord = await Post.find({city: record.city});
     if(!cityRecord[0]) {
       try {
          const dbRecord = await Post.create(record)
          console.log("Inserted which are not before into database");
       } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
       }
     } else {
       console.log('Record already exists');
       // Insert the update logic here
       // for example:
       // const recordUpdate = await Post.update(cityRecord[0].id, record);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.
Ideally, you will have to make changes in the `else` block of the code.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either uses same it work similar as it was before

Comment: It is still inserting twice time no stopping check works

Comment: You should check the `checkExistsfromDb` array because thats what decides if you should insert a record or update a record.

Comment: I can see existing records are available I am uploading same fille it is inserting twice time

Comment: @SunilDubey Can you elaborate in your question the part as how are the values assigned in checkExistsFromDb?

Comment: checkExistsFromDb means fetching data from database and checking if city match with my next insert data it should not insert

Comment: Let me explain it again fetchRecordFromFile is my file which I use to insert data into database. 

checkExistsfromDb are records which are already inserted probably from fetchRecordFromFile, now what I want check checkExistsfromDb's city is equal to from my file (fetchRecordFromFile) then not to insert it again otherwise insert it

Comment: @SunilDubey This should have been specified inthe question.
However, I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that it is not recommended to perform a database query inside a loop. Go for the insertMany is you want to insert multiple things and check through result.nModified or relevant field to check how many documents are inserted.

Go for UpdateMany if you want to update the data or insert some additional data using $set or $unset operator.